# drf model permissions in custom viewset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

at the moment i have a custom view for example:

```
class DocumentViewSet(RevisionMixin, viewsets.ViewSet):
    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```

and these models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...

class Document(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('company.Company', ...)
    ...
```

A user belongs to a company. A Document belongs also to a company. A user should only interact with a document view if the company from the document and from the user is the same.

On top of this separation a user can have normal Django model permissions like delete or add. Or another custom model permission.

Now i would like to check per view if a user belongs to the same company as the requested ressource and then check if the user have the permission to execute a specific action.

For example in the viewset destroy function above i would like to delete a document from database. So i would like to check if the requested user have the same company as the requested document and then i would like to check if the user have the delete permission for these model.

I try it with a custom permission:

```
class DocumentPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action == 'destroy':
            return request.user.has_perm('document_app.delete_document')
        return False

        if view.action == 'create':
            return request.user.has_perm('document_app.add_document')
        return False
        ...

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.company is obj.company:
            return True
        return False

class DocumentViewSet(RevisionMixin, viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, DocumentPermission]

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Document, id=pk)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        ...
```

This works for the DocumentViewSet but not for all of my models/viewsets because another objects have not direct foreign key to company.
So i would need to create some permission classes or have some ifelse in the has_object_permission function.

But is that the best solution?

Comment: Use [django-rest-framework-guardian](https://github.com/rpkilby/django-rest-framework-guardian)

Comment: Looks complicated. Is this really the best and simplest solution?

Comment: simple than writing your own

Comment: What do you mean you must do "it" for all actions? What is "it"?

Comment: Sorry my english is not so good. I update my question because i think i have not explain my intention correctly. I have read more about django-guardian and think that is not what i want because django guardian set/check permissions for a specific object but i would like to check permissions for a whole model with the addition that the company from the user and the requested ressource match.

Comment: @GauravDhameeja